# Why do some hockey players kneel as they take a shot?

Tags: technique, ice-hockey

I was watching the Rangers vs Islanders game, and McDonaugh scored a goal while down on one knee, a bit like [image: this picture].

Here is [video of the goal](http://video.nhl.com/videocenter/console?id=2014020838-201-ingame-h) at NHL website and on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzMSg2sreQY#t=47).

I've seen lots of players do this before, often when someone passes across the goal on a 2 on 1.

Is there any reason why they do it? Do you get more control/accuracy like that?

Answer (score 9):

I asked my friend, who played hockey in college, and she said that it is a combination of a few things:

- You turn some of your momentum into shot speed/power, if you do it in a single motion.  Your push off the back skate can be stronger when going down to a knee, and some of that is transferred into your lower stick arm (the right arm in the above picture).
- You are able to use more of your strength from the lower hand/arm/shoulder in that position.
- Some players may feel they have a higher degree of accuracy, but my friend wasn't sure whether this is true or not.

I also found that it specifically allows a shot that is higher in the net with power; for example, [this hockey tutorial](http://howtohockey.com/how-to-perfect-the-one-timer) shows how to do it.  They credit Brett Hull with popularizing it, and I can't say I know whether that's true or not (as my hockey watching days date to basically early Brett Hull but not before).

Answer (score 1):

It is simply because Ryan McDonaugh was not in the greatest position relative to the puck so rather than stopping the puck for a moment to position himself he got the shot off as quickly as possible in order to surprise Halák.